# Scaffold error : Type 'TypeVariable(T)' has no method 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, scaffold

i saw this code exemple from the official android website
i didnt change any thing in the gradle file and i got an error
my code and my imports :

```
@Composable
fun ScaffoldExample() {
    var presses by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                colors = topAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                    titleContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                ),
                title = {
                    Text("Top app bar")
                }
            )
        },
        bottomBar = {
            BottomAppBar(
                containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
            ) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    text = "Bottom app bar",
                )
            }
        },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(onClick = { presses++ }) {
                Icon(Icons.Default.Add, contentDescription = "Add")
            }
        }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(innerPadding),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                text =
                """
                    This is an example of a scaffold. It uses the Scaffold composable's parameters to create a screen with a simple top app bar, bottom app bar, and floating action button.

                    It also contains some basic inner content, such as this text.

                    You have pressed the floating action button $presses times.
                """.trimIndent(),
            )
        }
    }
}
```

my imports were :
package com.example.myapplication

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Add
import androidx.compose.material3.BottomAppBar
import androidx.compose.material3.FloatingActionButton
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBar
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.myapplication.ui.theme.MyApplicationTheme
```

but i got theese errors :

```
Type 'TypeVariable(T)' has no method 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate
Unresolved reference: mutableIntStateOf
This material API is experimental and is likely to change or to be removed in the future.
```

This is an example of a scaffold. It uses the Scaffold composable's parameters to create a screen with a simple top app bar, bottom app bar, and floating action button.

```
                It also contains some basic inner content, such as this text.

                You have pressed the floating action button $presses times.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `presses` variable when using it with `by` keyword. you have two options to fix it:

1. instead of using `by` just use normal `=` and then when you need the value use `.value` option:

   `var presses = remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }`

then you can use it like this:

```
`FloatingActionButton(onClick = { presses.value++ }) {
  Icon(Icons.Default.Add, contentDescription = "Add")
}`
```

2. you have two `imports` for the by keyword to work:

`import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue`

`import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue`